# What tags should we use for tablets?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Which tags should we use for the upcoming tablet releases? We didn't really talk about the classification when the phone was announced which led to some confusion, so I figured I would ask early.

Comment: Is there an actual, official product name for "Ubuntu for Tablets" and "Ubuntu for Phones"? To me that would seem like the sensible bet. Mobile/phones/tablet all have crossover with other devices.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.

Comment: It [seems that](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2013/02/releasing-the-ubuntu-touch-developer-preview-and-sdk-alpha/) "Ubuntu Touch" is the current name being used. Makes sense. I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [mobile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mobile), [phones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/phones) and [tablet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tablet) tags are all used for other things (interacting with phones and graphics tablet input, etc) so I don't think commandeering them is a great solution. Even in combination, it's not a great solution.

I'm fairly confident that the "product" is called **Ubuntu Touch** now, so I suggest we release [mobile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mobile) back into the wild (or nuke it for being too ambiguous) and migrate everything Touch-related to [ubuntu-touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch) (assuming this *is* its product name).

Layer on [phones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/phones) and [tablet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tablet), or even the actual device tag (why not?) as applicable.

Comment: That would be great, maybe also add the ubuntu-phone and ubuntu-tablet to it to be more specific.

Comment: The mobile tag got repurposed to specifically be ubuntu on phones, the other two are still overlapping though.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Well I disagree with that repurposing. We shouldn't be using generic words ("a mobile [phone]" in the UK means is "a cell [phone]") for specific things: people will just mistag things.

Comment: Right, but things like ubuntu-mobile don't make sense either, we made that mistake when we launched with "ubuntu-desktop" and its friends.

Comment: What doesn't make sense about `ubuntu-mobile`? `ubuntu-desktop` is what we assume every question to be about, unless specified otherwise. `ubuntu-mobile` is, effectively, a different official distro. `mobile` on its own does no longer specify what the question is about: It may refer to ubuntu-desktop on mobile devices, it may refer to ubuntu-on-phones or ubuntu-on-tablets (ubuntu-mobile). These *need* to be separated as they're inherently different - and different from ubuntu-desktop on a standard PC.

Comment: @FEichinger Because they're [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). When the site launched we had `ubuntu-desktop`, and it ended up being worthless. It doesn't really say anything, you're better off classifying it unity, gnome, nautilus, etc.

Comment: @Oli if we do `ubuntu-mobile` how do tag subscriptions work? Would I need to tell the team to resubscribe or does SE handle all that?

Comment: @JorgeCastro How is `ubuntu-mobile` a meta tag, as opposed to `mobile`? We classify Ubuntu for phones and Ubuntu for tablets as "Ubuntu Mobile" that makes it the "product name", for all we know. That's just like `ubuntu-one` in that regard.

Comment: Because we don't really need it, you could just tag them phone and tablet, but for some reason we have it.

Comment: @JorgeCastro As we seem to have a name now, I think it's best we start transitioning to ubuntu-touch instead of mobile and link synomonisinate touch to ubuntu-touch (as people will assume touch, which is generic is it)

Comment: Sounds good to me! Woo!

Comment: Good points Oli. Now what Jorge asks was also what I wanted to know. Does the system do it automatically or do subscribed users need to update themselves.

Comment: @JorgeCastro What are they subscribed to? Give me an example URL and we can do a test run with some made-up tags to see what happens.

Comment: `mobile` is the tag.

Comment: @JorgeCastro I did a test and yeah it's going to break everything. But I really can't stand "mobile"... I'm informing anybody who I can imagine might care but talk to your people too! They'll notice when the RSS feed starts 404ing.

Comment: Ok we'll tell the engineering folks to resub to stuff, works for me.

Answer (score 3):

### The problem:

We will need a way to differentiate between using phones and tablets *with* Ubuntu (as in, syncing with your Android phone or Tablet for example), and as Ubuntu (devices), that is, with Ubuntu as the OS.

### My suggestion:

- **Phones:**

  - [ubuntu-phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-phone) - for Phones running Ubuntu.
  - [phones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/phones) - For Ubuntu related Phone tasks - including but not
    limited to: running Ubuntu on phones, using phones with Ubuntu, and
    related activities.

---

- **Tablets:**

  - [ubuntu-tablet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-tablet) - For Tablets running Ubuntu.
  - [tablets](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tablets) - For Ubuntu related Tablet tasks - including but not
    limited to: running Ubuntu on Tablets, using Tablets with Ubuntu, and
    related activities.

---

- **Desktops**

<s>[ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop) (yes, Ubuntu-Desktop) for desktop related questions (that are not applicable to mobile devices).</s> Since we assume this, it would not be needed.

---

### The cons:

I admit that this suggestion is not without flaws. We already have been working hard to kill the [ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop) tag, but in the light of things, we may need to revive this tag because it *is* one of the 3 form factors and users *will* need to ask about it.

However, this would potentially introduce minor (potentially major) tag chaos when users begin using it for questions that don't need it.

[image: Cute picture]

P.S. customary cat picture.

Comment: I don't see why we need to revive the ubuntu-desktop tag at all.

Comment: @rolandiXor, I am here!

Comment: We don't need `ubuntu-desktop`. That is what we assume a question to be about, unless anything else is specified.

Comment: +1 I like yours better.

Comment: @Gui you made it! :D

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

- [mobile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mobile) for Tablets and Phones that come with Ubuntu pre-installed or not and for any other general mobile device.
- [phones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/phones) for Phones that come with Ubuntu pre-installed (Explained in the info about the tag when used)
- [tablet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tablet) for Tablets that come with Ubuntu pre-installed (Explained in the info about the tag when used)